# Using Apache to make a virtual host with the same domain name?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, mod-wsgi

I'm sure there's a name for this and I'm probably just searching wrong. Anyways, is it possible to set up virtual hosts on the same domain name by using information after the '/'

For example

host1 => example.com/siteA/

host2 => example.com/siteB/

It might be helpful for me to mention that my goal is to host PHP content on siteA and mod_wsgi content on siteB (I'm using flask).

I just want to separate all of the back-end configuration settings using virtual hosts. Perhaps I'm thinking of this the wrong way and there's a more proper manner of doing this sort of thing.

Comment: It's much, much better to use subdomains in this scenario. Trying to use subdirectories gets very complicated and error-prone very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, virtual hosts don't work that way.  You can use them to set up siteA.example.com and siteB.example.com, but not example.com/siteA and example.com/siteB.

However, you can still accomplish it by using a structure like this:

```
# global configuration
<Location /siteA>
    # siteA configuration
</Location>
<Location /siteB>
    # siteB configuration
</Location>
```

Most of the directives that can go in a vhost configuration can also go in a `<Location>` section, so I don't think there are many limitations to setting things up this way.  Check the allowed Context of the directives you want to use in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html) to be sure.